# Laravel - passing variable from controller to view - undefined variable

Tags: laravel, view, controller

i'm new to Laravel, but I've been working at it. I've searched the site but can't find specific help. I've created a variable in my Controller (and checked it a 1000 times against a tutorial) and passed it to the view, but the browser gives an error *"Undefined variable"*.

`$company` holds the table row after posting. I suspect it may have something to do with it being an array.

Controller resource function show

```
public function show($comp_id)
{
    $company = Company::find($comp_id);
    return view('companies.show')->with('company', $company);   
}
```

And in the view:

```
@section('content')
    <h1>{{ $company->CompanyName }}</h1>
```

I'm sure it's a simple error, but any help please?

Comment: I saw many syntax errors in there.

Comment: Check if dd($comp_id) in the controller return  the right value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to set the `show($id)` to the specific id name in my table column.
`public function show($id) 
    $company = Company::where('Comp_id', $id)->first();
    return view('companies.show')->withCompany($company);`
Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: All is well that ends well. Could you please accept your answer so that others are aware that this question was resolved?

Comment: Ok, didn't know I could accept my own answer, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Sanzeeb, your syntax has several errors. Let's try fixing those first.

In your controller please modify your method like so:

```
public function show($comp_id)
{
    $company = Company::find($comp_id);

    return view('companies.show')->with('company', $company);
}
```

Then please modify your fiew like so:

```
@section('content')

<h1>{{ $company->CompanyName }}</h1>
```

And let's see if that helps.

Comment: Eitan, your quote of my code shows a semi-colon between the variable and the class, but in my submission it did have an equal sign. Your bracketing in the 'return view' is different from what Tom Kopah suggested. I tested both, but still get: ErrorException in 67ad97908c79b9baf76653c370849a03da33d1aa.php line 5:
Undefined variable: company (View: C:\Sites\AI\resources\views\companies\show.blade.php)

Comment: Sorry gents, this is my first question on SO so I'm still learning the syntaxes and protocol. It seems @Pauwelyn made some errors in transcribing my code from the images I posted in my question. There is a bracket at the end of the `return view` line and I do have a  `@stop` at the end of my View code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix some things. try this please.

In your controller please modify your method like so:

```
public function show($comp_id)
{
    $company = Company::find($comp_id);

    return view('companies.show', compact('company'));
}
```

And in the view:

```
@section('content')
<h1>{{ $company->CompanyName }}</h1>
@stop
```

Comment: I believe this is syntax for Laravel 5, while PDevH's question implies he uses Laracel 4.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ well, in that case lets wait for him to tell us. and if so, Then we will change :)

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.3. I've tested all variations of your suggestions, specifically the bracketing and use of `compact` vs `with`. No luck.

Comment: Did you added 'use App\Company;` to the namespace?